# Is $\pi(n)$ a Rational Function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Are there some two-variable polynomials $P(n,\log n)$ and $Q(n,\log n)$ which we have the bellow equation for prime counting function $\pi(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{n}$?
$$\pi(n) =  \Bigl{\lfloor} \frac{P(n,\log n)}{Q(n, \log n)} \Bigr{\rfloor}$$

Note: According to the Prime Number Theorem such these polynomials should satisfy the bellow limit condition.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{P(n,\log n) \times \log n}{Q(n, \log n) \times n}  =1 $$

Comment: I highly suspect the answer to be no, but I can't prove it.

Comment: I suspect the growth of $\pi$ is too irregular for this to be possible. For example [it was recently shown](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2015/181-1/p07) that for some constant $K$, the quantity $\pi(x+K)-\pi(x)$ is infinitely often over (say) $10$ (and of course is infinitely often zero). Can polynomials $P$ and $Q$ as above be chosen to get this behavoir?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen No. Your idea completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

With looking to the method advised in the Jeppe Stig Nielsen's comment we can complete the proof for the claim which there aren't such these polynomials.

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4600v2.pdf) it's proved which for every $m$ we have:

$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} p_{n+m} - p_{n} < \infty $$

and thus if the above polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ exist then for some fixed $k$ and infinitely many $n$s we should have

$$ \frac{P(n+m,\log (n+m))}{Q(n+m, \log (n+m))} - \frac{P(n,\log n)}{Q(n, \log n)} > k-1 $$

and for some other $n$s (again, infinitely many times) because of existance of intervals of length $m+2$ which are free of the primes(haven't any primes) we should have

$$ \frac{P(n+m,\log (n+m))}{Q(n+m, \log (n+m))} - \frac{P(n,\log n)}{Q(n, \log n)} <1 $$

this means which the rational function $ \frac{P(n+m,\log (n+m))}{Q(n+m, \log (n+m))} - \frac{P(n,\log n)}{Q(n, \log n)}  $ which is a function of $n$ should oscillate infinitely many times between $1$ and $k-1$ but such a function for large $n$'s is increasing or decreasing(this claim can be proved just with calculating the derivative) and thus $\pi(n)$ can not be written as a rational function of the form $\Bigl{\lfloor} \frac{P(n,\log n)}{Q(n, \log n)} \Bigr{\rfloor}$.

Comment: Yes,  that was what I thought when I wrote that comment. I hope we are not overlooking something. However this proof uses theorems that were not known before [Zhāng's 2013 result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang). Maybe one can avoid that.